# Moq Using Lazy Loading in Constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

I ran into a strange problem today - I was writing a unit test around a SIM object. It asserts that when the SIM object is updated and the PIN attempts remaining has changed, it will call a particular method. The test looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void TestUpdateSimInfoWithPinAttemptsChangedCallsOnPinAttemptsRemaining()
{
    var info = new SimPinInfo {PinAttemptsRemaining = 10};

    var sim = new Mock<Sim>(info);

    info.PinAttemptsRemaining = 2;

    sim.Object.UpdateSimInfo(info);

    sim.Verify(s => s.FireOnPinAttemptsRemaining(), Times.Once());
}
```

So the mock SIM object is created with 10 PIN attempts remaining. The `SimPinInfo` object then has the `PinAttemptsRemaining` value reduced to 2 before being passed to the `UpdateSimInfo()` method.

SIM constructor (trimmed for clarity):

```
internal Sim(SimPinInfo info) : this()
{
     _pinAttemptsRemaining = info.PinAttemptsRemaining;
     _pukAttemptsRemaining = info.PukAttemptsRemaining;
     ......
}
```

And the `UpdateSimInfo()` method (trimmed):

```
internal void UpdateSimInfo(SimPinInfo info)
{
    lock(_locker)
    {
        if (_pinAttemptsRemaining != info.PinAttemptsRemaining)
        {
            Log("PinAttemptsRemaining changed");
            _pinAttemptsRemaining = info.PinAttemptsRemaining;
            FireOnPinAttemptsRemaining();
        }
        .....
    }
}
```

A pretty simple test - what should happen is the above if statement will be true (pin attempts remaining has changed) so the `OnPinAttemptsRemaining` event will be fired. However, the test failed (although not all the time - it passed when I slowly stepped through the code!). What was happening was the if statement was false - both `_pinAttemptsRemaining` and `info.PinAttemptsRemaining` were 2. It appears that the SIM mock is not actually created when expected - when the `info.PinAttemptsRemaining` was 10.

To demonstrated this, I added a comment:

```
var sim = new Mock<Sim>(info);
info.PinAttemptsRemaining = 2;
Console.WriteLine("SIM's pin attempts = " + sim.Object.PinAttemptsRemaining);
```

I also put a breakpoint in the SIM object's constructor. The breakpoint was hit when stepping over the `Console.WriteLine` line, not the `new Mock...` line. So the object is not being created until needed.

I believe this is called lazy-loading or lazy-evaluation.

There were various workaround to this behaviour - I ended up creating a new `SimPinInfo` object to pass to `UpdateSimInfo()`.

Has anyone come across this behaviour before? I couldn't find any references to it.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read you're trying to test a Mock.

```
sim.Object.UpdateSimInfo(info);
```

Mocks are meant to substitute dependencies, you don't use them to substitute the code you mean to test. Without seeing the whole code, I'd guess that you don't even need a Mock to test this behaviour. Assuming that FireOnPinAttemptsRemaining raises an event I'd recommend something like this for a test method:

```
[Test]
public void TestUpdateSimInfoWithPinAttemptsChangedCallsOnPinAttemptsRemaining()
{
    int eventFiredCount = 0;
    var info = new SimPinInfo {PinAttemptsRemaining = 10};
    var sim = Sim(info);
    sim.OnPinAttemptsRemaining += (sender, e) => { eventFiredCount++; };

    info.PinAttemptsRemaining = 2;
    sim.UpdateSimInfo(info);

    Assert.AreEqual(1, eventFiredCount);
}
```

I'm not 100% on the event handler since I don't know the Fire method is raising an event or not, or the event name, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I started off with unit tests that actually waited for events on a different thread, using Monitors etc. The next step looked something like your code which worked fine and I finally ended up using the Mock code in my question. I'll probably go back to your style but can you explain the "substitute dependencies/substitute code" comment please. Cheers.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to explain it. Let's say you have a service which wraps data access. DataService. It talks directly to your database. You have other code that uses DataService to retrieve and save information. Now you want to test some of that code which is going to need to fetch data from the DataService. Mocks allow you to test that code in isolation of the data service by mocking the data service. For instance I'll give the data service a contract interface called IDataService. By using Mock<IDataService> you can set up expected scenarios without needing "real" data connections.